# Im creating a php script to download videos from a folder on my computer. The video downloads but it doesn't play. I even used file type videos/mp4

Tags: php, download

i used
header("File-Type: video/mp4);
//other headers

Then
readfile('uploads/'. $videoname);

Video downloads but doesn't play

Answer (score 0):

This might helps:

```
$file_url = $_GET['link'];           
header('Content-Type: video/mp4'); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . 
basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```